# PHP's _get & _set or unique get and set functions for each variable?

Tags: php, get, set, encapsulation, accessor

PHP has _get and _set functions built in. Is it better to write my own get and set functions for each variable or use the built in functions with a ton of if else if? What are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: It would probably help if you explain why you need to use `__get` and `__set`, as opposed to just public fields.  You can always change to `__get` and `__set` later.

Comment: I want to be able to check that the data is legal and some of the data needs reformatting before being saved to the database,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__get` and `__set` are magic methods that should usually be used to solve difficult problems rather than to be used as a design basis.

For instance, I found myself on a project where I had to analyze a site that used OOP with deep inheritance (> 2) and one of the important base classes had a public property called `name`. However, it also had getters and setters (`getName`, `setName`) that accessed that property for the mere purpose of  getting and setting it. Many classes called `getName` and just as many accessed the `name` property directly! Not great design.

The magic methods allowed me to solve the problem by renaming the property to `_name` and making it private, forcing all requests to the property through the getters and setters.

This being said, there's no need for getters and setters if you're just treating a property like a variable. In that case, just make the property public!

In your case, since there is validating/sanitizing going on, you should employ getters and setters and code them directly as methods (rather than unnecessarily incurring the overhead from the magic methods).

Comment: I'm guessing there was a very large number of places where $instance -> name was being done, right?  Because I personally think it would have been better to change the classes that did that to use getName()/setName() instead and make $name protected.  I suppose you could have your __get and __set methods issue an E_NOTICE or E_DEPRECATED when called, that way stuff would still work but you'd be alerted where you weren't doing it through the setters/getters.  That's just me though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I handle this problem.

```
  final public function __set($key, $value) {
    $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
      $this->data[$key] = $this->$method($value);
    } else {
      $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
  }  


  final public function __get($key) {
    $method = 'get' . ucfirst($key);
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
      return $this->$method($this->data[$key]);
    } else {
      return $this->data[$key];
    }
  }
```

If you have a custom handler for a property, it gets called (assuming it's named getProperty).  Otherwise, the default get/set magic method is used.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to go by the rule that if you have complex get or set logic then add a separate get or set method. If you're doing something simple you can leverage `__get` or `__set` when you would otherwise repeat yourself in a lot of custom get/set methods.